# Taxes on an NY summer internship

Tags: united-states, withholding, payroll-taxes, tennessee

I am a TN resident who will be doing a 12 week internship this summer in upstate NY. My salary is around 2.3k every two weeks. What would this be after taxes? Would my company take care of state and federal taxes?

Comment: Just ask your company :)

Comment: Will you have any other income this tax year? Your company will withhold state and federal taxes at a standard rate, but your total income for the year will affect the size of any tax refund / bill.

Comment: Your company will probably withhold NY state taxes; it will *not* withhold any TN state taxes. What taxes you will own for each state depends on any agreements between TN and NY regarding taxation. (You may be double-taxed, or you may receive a credit in one state for taxes paid to the other.)

Answer (score -1):

That's just over 12K. You will probably get around 1k taken out for the whole year.

Ask your employer for the State tax income form and there is an option to add an additional amount on to take out for state taxes.
I used to have the state take an additional $5 out for taxes each check just to be safe.

Also claim 0 for dependents

The good news is most likely you will end up getting around $300 back when you claim your taxes.